# "Dependency could not be resolved" for Asp.Net Core proj referencing EntityFramework 6.1.3 proj

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have the following project structure:

> Proj.sln
>
> - Proj.Core (xproj lib, references: nothing)
> - Proj.Services (xproj lib, referencs: core, data)
> - Proj.Data (csproj lib, references: core)
> - Proj.Bootstrapper (xproj lib references: everything)
> - Proj.WebApi (xproj lib, references: core, services)

I have moved the project to Asp.Net Core, but still rely on the full Entity Framework - version 6.1.3. To achieve this, I am following [this example.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6)
The xproj class libraries that rely on a reference to Proj.Data, all have the below framework attribute in project.json:

```
 "frameworks": {
    "net452": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Proj.Data": {
          "target": "project"
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

However, when I build a project depending on Proj.Data, such as Proj.Bootstrapper, I am getting the following error:

*Error  NU1001  The dependency Proj.Data could not be resolved.*

Here is Bootstrapper's project.json:

```
{
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": false,
    "xmlDoc": false
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework": "6.1.3",
    "Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "4.0.0",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1",
    "Proj.Core": "1.0.0-*",
    "Proj.Services": "1.0.0-*",
    "Proj.WebApi": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Extensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt": "5.1.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "net452": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Proj.Data": {
          "target": "project"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "version": "1.0.0-*"
}
```

And, for what it is worth, my project.config in my Proj.Data project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

Also worth mentioning is that I downgraded my Proj.Data framework from net46 to net452 as the compiler was complaining.

Guidance appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you (currently) can reference `xproj` from `csproj`, as you are doing in Proj.Data. Also, do you still get the NuGet error when restoring using `dotnet restore`?

Comment: Thanks, Nate. I was actually able to make a reference to Core from Data previously. But, as a test, I took it out and it still breaks. Yes, if I run dotnet restore from Bootstrapper, it throws the error I mentioned above. Personally, I think the problem has to do with framework versioning as mentioned here.  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToReferenceAnExistingNETFrameworkProjectInAnASPNETCore10WebApp.aspx

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was because of using both .NET Framework and .NET Core.

I was missing .NET Framework 4.6.2.

After installing `Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.2 Developer Pack` from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53321 the problem was solved.

I guess in your case you are missing the .NET Framework version 4.5.2